# Help identify this Lego set - light blues, browns, and dark purples

Tags: set-identification

I got a mixed set and have worked through them but have a couple I can't identify:

[image: part 1 not built by us]
[image: part 2]
(click to enlarge images)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These both look like part of [Naida's Spa Secret](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41072-1) 41072.

[image]

Looking for unique parts, the dark purple Round Corner 4x4 Macaroni in photo 1 looked unique enough, and this is how I found it.

Comment: Just beat me! It would be nice to avoid multiple people answering at the same time...

Comment: Unbelievable you look to be absolutely spot on. One happy girl tomorrow to build another set out of her mixed bag